# Steering wheel gives a "cluck" sound

Tags: honda, civic, steering-wheel

I have a Honda Civic VTI, 1997 model, automatic transmission. When I turn the steering wheel all the way to the left or right, it gives me a loud "cluck" sound. What is it?

Comment: Is this when you are stopped, or while driving?

Comment: Any chance this might be related to the wobble?  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/128/my-car-wobbles-while-driving

Comment: I don't think that it is related to the wobble. It is there before that problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it resembles a repetitive knocking or loud clicking noise, it's probably your CV joint.

Comment: I think my car has this problem. If I'm turning left, the noise would be from the right hand side CV joint, right?

Comment: Probably. In some makes / models it can be difficult to tell but if you check under the car and look at the boots on the axles you should be able to see if one is torn. You might also be able to feel vibration coming from the front of the vehicle when you accelerate.

Answer (score 2):

If it when you reach full-travel on the steering wheel:

- single "cluck" while stopped -- a worn tie rod end
- see image for location: http://repairguide.autozone.com/znetrgs/repair_guide_content/en_us/images/0900c152/80/18/f9/e5//small/0900c1528018f9e5.jpg
- a "cluck-cluck-cluck" sound while moving -- a worn CV joint
- see image for location: http://repairguide.autozone.com/znetrgs/repair_guide_content/en_us/images/0900c152/80/18/f9/7c//small/0900c1528018f97c.jpg